# Generate code with null-conditional delegate invocation

Tags: c#, codedom

I cannot seem to find the null-conditional operator in CodeDOM.

I'd like to generate the following code:

```
 myDelegate?.Invoke(this, null);
```

but I cannot find the right CodeExpression for the `?.` operator.

Which one is it?

Comment: There is none, CodeDom is quite old and does not get every compiler-feature. Just use the classic if-null-approach.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Is there a modern equivalent that is already included in the netstandard? Using roslyn requires downloading and delivering many DLLs.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Can you add that as an answer so I can mark it as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

> There is none, CodeDom is quite old and does not get every compiler-feature. Just use > the classic if-null-approach